# Singleton Derived Class with multiple bases of non-default constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, multiple-inheritance

I have a class derived from multiple base classes and I want to make it a singleton.  Problem is the derived and base classes do not use default constructors and take arguments, so I'm confused how I can manage.  I want to be able to pass the arguments to what would have been the constructor, but I only want possible to do once (I don't want it to be a setter).  My only solution was a static bool value in the getInstance() member of the derived class.

Basic case:

```
//Singleton Derived Class with multiple bases of non-default constructors
class base1 {
    public:
        base1(int* value) :
              val_{value} {;}
        ~base1();
    private:
        int val_;
}

class base2 {
    public:
        base2(int* value) :
              val_{value} {;}
        ~base2();
    private:
        int val_;      
}

class derived : public base1, public base2 {
    public:
        derived(int* value) :
                base1{value},   //Base 1 constructor call
                base2{value},   //Base 2 constructor call
                val_{value} {;}
        ~derived();
    private:
        int val_;
}

//Creation
derived newDerived(&value);
```

Attempt to make it singleton-like?

```
//Lets make it a singleton
class base1 {
    public:
        base1(); //Can I pass the construtor anything?
        ~base1();
    private:
        int val_;
}

class base2 {
    public:
        base2(); //Can I pass the construtor anything?
        ~base2();
    private:
        int val_;      
}

class derived : public base1, public base2 {
    public:
        static derived& getInstance(int* value) {
            static bool init;
            if (!init) {
                base1::val_ = value;
                base2::val_ = value;
                init=true;
            }
            static derived instance;
            return instance;
        }
        derived(int* value) {;}
        ~derived();
    private:
        derived(derived const&) = delete;           //Copy construct
        derived(derived&&) = delete;                //Move construct
        derived& operator=(derived const&) = delete;//Copy assign
        derived& operator=(derived &&) = delete;    //Move assign
        int val_;
}

//Creation
derived::getInstance(&value);
```

I'm looking for some direction on how I should go about this, or maybe reasons I shouldn't do it at all? Thanks

Comment: Just pass them into constructor of this singleton. Storing it as static local variable is not really a good idea, besides creating instance using default constructor you give up control over instance lifetime.

Comment: Mayne I'm over thinking.  If this uses lazy initialization, i can hand off 'int* value' to the derived constructor and leave everything as it was, is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Why do you want singleton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Instead of reference I am using pointer here. This is just an example hence I am not making this singleton as thread safe. Also declare a default constructor as private so that it can not be instantiate.

```
class base1 {
public:
     base1(int* value) : val_(*value) {}
    ~base1() {};
    private:
        int val_;
};

class base2 {
 public:
    base2(int* value) :
    val_(*value ) { }
    ~base2() {};
private:
    int val_;
};

class derived : public base1, public base2 {
    private:
    derived(int* value) :
    base1(value),   //Base 1 constructor call
    base2(value),   //Base 2 constructor call
    val_(*value) {}
   ~derived() {};
     private:
     int val_;
     static derived* driv;

    public:
  static derived* getInstance(int* value);
};

 derived* derived::driv = NULL;

derived* derived::getInstance(int* value)
{
    if (driv == NULL)
    {
      driv = new derived(value);
    }
  return driv;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks.  I guess I don't understand the upsides of the pointer vs reference method though, I still need to explicitly delete the copy/assigment/move constructors, right?

Comment: You just need to utilize the base class destructor to release the memory. Please see online document how to release the memory of a singleton class.